# Consultando em uma lista (IN) - Predicate e Specification - JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, rest, spring-boot, criteria

Olá, tenho que criar uma consulta dinâmica baseada no seguinte cenário em uma aplicação RESTFUL utilizando Springboot e JPA (estou utilizando JpaSpecificationExecutor):

Possuo duas classes entidades (Entity), a primeira é a de produtos:

```
Produto
Long id;
String descricaoDetalhada;
List<Categoria> categorias;
```

E a segunda é referente a categoria:

```
Categoria
Long id;
String nome;
```

Como podem ver um produto pode possuir várias categorias.

Tenho um endpoint com dois parâmetros: `Descricao` e `Categorias`.

Abaixo estou enviando o código da classe Specification onde preciso criar o segundo Predicate para realizar o filtro por categorias, pois o filtro por descrição já esta pronto.

```
    public class ProdutoSpecification implements Specification<Produto>{

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            private String descricao;
            private String categorias;

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            public ProdutoSpecification(String descricao, String categorias) {
                super();
                this.descricao = descricao;
                this.categorias = categorias;
            }

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Produto> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

                if (descricao != null) {

                    String PalavraChave[] = descricao.split(" ");

                    //Predicate para o filtro por descrição
                    for (String filtro : PalavraChave) {
                        predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(root.get("descricaoDetalhada")), "%"+ filtro.toUpperCase() + "%"));
                    }

                }

                //Predicate para o filtro por categorias
                if (categorias != null) {
                    List<Long> ids = URL.decodeLongList(categorias);

                //AQUI DEVERÁ TER A INSTRUÇAO QUE CRIA O PREDICATE ONDE VERIFICA SE UM CÓDIGO DE CATEGORIA É PRESENTE EM ALGUM PRODUTO.
                }

                return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            }
        }
```

A variável categorias na classe é transformada em um `List<Long>` ids.

Como crio um Predicate onde verifico se um das categorias presente no produto esta dentro da `ids` atendendo assim o parâmetro de consulta? Assim eu conseguiria filtrar os produtos que possuem determinadas categorias.

A região comentada no código irá receber a instrução para criação do Predicate.

Atenciosamente,

Gonzaga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Long[] tipos = URL.decodeLongList(categorias);
    if (tipos!=null) {
        predicates.add(root.join("categorias").get("id").in(tipos));
    }
```

Comment: Weslley, passei a madrugada inteira tentando achar esta solução, foi perfeita. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Blz, boa sorte!